# Look for last or first period in a string and add week number

Tags: php

I have a string that is a filename it looks something like this:

```
strfilename =    "document99_bob.pdf"
```

I would like to insert the week number for example today is Thursday so that would be `_4` right after bob but before `.pdf` or sometimes it will be a `.doc` or something else.

```
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday =4
Friday = 5
Saturday = 6
Sunday = 7
```

so the end result will look like this:

```
stringfilename =     "document99_bob_4.pdf"
```

Is there a way to look for the last or first period in the string and then just add the week number ?

Thanks

Comment: `explode()` on period then glue parts together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use explode on the filename, add the number, then stick it back together:

```
$strfilename = "document99_bob.pdf";
$strfilename = explode(".", $strfilename);
$strfilename[0] .= "_" . date("N"); // adds a number corresponding to the day of the week
$strfilename = implode(".", $strfilename);
```